# Count display for id unqiue

Tags: php, mysql, count

The following code is not working:

```
<?php 
        $sql = 'SELECT sum(display) AS nb_total FROM tracking where id_site ="'.$id_site.'"';
        $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.''.mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($req); 
        echo $data['nb_total']; 
?>
```

help me please

Comment: I think you need to remove the double quotes around `$idsite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct this line like this

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(display) AS nb_total FROM tracking where id_site ='$id_site'";
```

Comment: $id_site contains what?

Comment: Please echo  $sql and what you get just let me know.

Comment: SELECT sum(display) AS nb_total FROM tracking where id_site ='34'

Comment: Your input $id_site is exist or not in database table?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I was wrong variable, it's just anything! The application is good : <pre><code><?php $sql = "SELECT sum(display) AS nb_total FROM tracking where id_site ='$id'"; ?></code></pre>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(display) AS nb_total FROM tracking where id_site =$id_site";
```

Comment: What is the datatype of $id_site ?

Comment: I think the datatype is just an integer. So there is no need for quotes.

Comment: Sorry the datatype is int()

Comment: What is its datatype? Have you tried the new answer ?